# На странице выдвижения на выборы не переведён текст

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/3, нажать "выдвинуть свою кандидатуру". Текст на кнопке не переведён.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11554

Предложил перевод:

> Выдвинуть свою кандидатуру

Comment: Выдвинуть свой перевод

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хочу Оскар.

Comment: А ромбариум не желаете? :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ цена вопроса? :D

Comment: Скоро узнаем, я думаю.